# Onclick hide div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link that shows/hides a content within a div upon click, what I'm trying to do is have a button that will hide a specific div(the content in sectiontohide1) within the div(sectiontohide)upon click. I've got the Javascript working for the first link(sectiontohide) and it works but I can't figure out how to get the second link to hide the div

```
<a id="trackAttendance1"  onclick="loadtable('sectiontohide');"      class="trackAttendance" href="#">Track Absences</a>
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display:none;">
<table>
    <div id="sectiontohide1">
         <tr>
             <td>Web Programming Seminar</td>
             <th id="absent" rowspan="2">Absent</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>TUESDAY 2:00-3:00 - 21/02/2017</td>
         </tr>
    </div>

        <td>Management in IT</td>
        <th id="absent" rowspan="2">Absent</th>

        <tr>
        <td>FRIDAY 9:00-11:00 - 24/02/2017</td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Web Programming Lecture</td>
        <th id="absent" rowspan="2">Absent</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>FRIDAY 12:00-1:00 - 24/02/2017</td>
      </tr>
</table>

<a id="trackAttendance1"  onclick="hidediv('sectiontohide1');" class="close"     href="#">Hide Element</a>
```

My Javascript for showing/hiding the table

```
 function loadtable(id){
 var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

 if(divelement.style.display =='none')
 divelement.style.display = 'block';
 else
    divelement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: well if you got the first one working, then surely the second one is the same.  replace your "onclick="hidediv('sectiontohide1');" to "loadtable('sectiontohide1');"

Comment: One side note: an ID can be only used on time in a HTML document. So replace `id="absent"` on your elements with a class (`class="absent"`) for example. You could also use data attributes.

Comment: The `div#sectiontohide1` is not allowed a this place because you can only use valid table elements as children of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loadtable` function actually toggles the visibility of the element by the given id.

So you can run it for showing / hiding for the other parts too. For this it should be sufficient to change the click handler of the close button to `loadtable('sectiontohide1');`

But there are some other issues too, for example :

- A div can be placed in a table only if it is surrounded by a `<td></td>` or `<th></th>`
- `<th>` tag is for header so use it only on top of the table, you can use css for styling the cells
- `<td>` and `<th>` tags should always be surrounded by a `<tr></tr>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were on the right track. To just `hide` the div, try something like:

```
function hidediv(id) {
  var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
  divelement.style.display = 'none';
}
```